# Passing lambda expression as a method parameter with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, lambda, fluentvalidation

I'm making use of FluentValidation to do some server-side validation with my program. In order to make use of some custom validation I am using the `must` validator that allows you to pass in a predicate and return a bool to test whether or not the validation was successful. The validation I am attempting involves checking whether a string exists inside an array.

These details are largely irrelevant however, as simply I need to be able to pass a predicate into a method alongside a second `string[]` variable.

Below is my validation method:

```
public bool StringInArray(Func<string> predicate, string[] testArray)
        {
            if(testArray.Contains(predicate.Invoke()))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

And here is where I am calling this method.

```
RuleFor(p => p.Funder)
                .Must(StringInArray(p => p, funderStrings));
```

`funderStrings` is the array of who's contents I am checking. `p.Funder` is the string that I am checking for inside of the array.

The `p => p` argument is incorrect, and I am getting a `Delegate 'Func<string>' does not take 1 argument` compilation error. I am unsure how I should be passing the string into the `StringInArray` method.

Comment: how is this supposed to work? What is the StringInArray method supposed to do? you call `testArray.Contains(string)` with the result of a `string myMethod()` essentially.

Comment: I need to be able to test that a string is present within an array. The problem is that I cannot simply pass a string from the `.Must` method, as it requires that the string is accessed through a predicate. Therefore I need to pass the predicate containing my test string into the `StringInArray` method and be able to access it inside the method.

Comment: but the way you actually do it, you pass the result of StringInArray (which is a bool, not a predicate) and inside of StringInArray, my comment applies

Comment: The issue is that `p => p` is the signature for a Func<string, string>, as it takes an argument (p) and returns a value (also p). A Func<string>- i.e. a function that takes no parameters and produces a string - cannot take a parameter, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Either you want this:

```
    public bool StringInArray(Func<string, string> conversion, string[] testArray)
    {
        if (testArray.Any((s) => s.Equals(conversion(s))))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    ...
    RuleFor(p => p.Funder).Must(() => StringInArray(p => p, funderStrings));
```

or this:

```
    public Func<bool> StringInArray(string s, string[] testArray)
    {
        return () => testArray.Contains(s);
    }
    ...
    RuleFor(p => p.Funder).Must(() => StringInArray(p => p, funderStrings));
```

Please elaborate further what you exactly expect the `StringInArray` method to do, the `Must` method to receive & do